# Publish Collections Based on URL in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

Pseudocode:

```
Meteor.publish 'stuff', ->
    if this.userId
        return doStuffForLoggedInUsers(this.userId)
    else if url matches '/some_url/:user_api_key'
        return doStuffForApiKey(apiKey)
    else
        return null
```

A solution using Iron Router would be optimal, but a non routing framework solution would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

### client

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('postsWithKey', {
    path: '/posts/:apiKey',
    template: 'posts',
    before: function() {
      this.subscribe('posts', this.params.apiKey);
    }
  });

  return this.route('posts', {
    before: function() {
      this.subscribe('posts');
    }
  });
});
```

### server

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(apiKey) {
  check(apiKey, Match.Optional(String));

  if (apiKey) {
    return Posts.find({key: apiKey});
  } else if (this.userId) {
    return Posts.find({owner: this.userId});
  }
});
```

---

When the route with an api key is run, the client will activate the `posts` subscription with the key. On the server, one cursor is returned if the key exists, otherwise a different cursor is returned if the user is logged in. You could do more sophisticated validation of the key - e.g. throw an error if it doesn't exist in the database.